# h12 request timeout heroku server for nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have nodejs code deployed on heroku server.

I am facing H12 request timeout issue

[image]

here is the db connection with pgsql and that is in async

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");
import nodeEnvFile = require("node-env-file");
import { Query } from "src/models/query";
nodeEnvFile(".env");

const config = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_IP,
    database: process.env.DB,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    max: 5, // max number of connection can be open to database
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
    ssl: true
};

const pool = new Pool(config);

export class DB {
    static async query(queryInfo: Query): Promise<any> {
        // to hold undefined values while stringfy json
        const replacer = (_key, value) => typeof value === "undefined" ? null : value;
        let _arguments = "()";
        if (queryInfo.arguments) {
            _arguments = `('${JSON.stringify(queryInfo.arguments, replacer)}'::json)`;
        }
        const query = `select * from ${queryInfo.name} ${_arguments} as info;`;
        console.log(query);
        try {
            return pool.query(query)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("response", response);
                    return response.rows[0].info;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Db Error : ", err);
                    throw err;
                });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("err", err);
            throw err;
        }
    }
}
```

here is how i am calling this db

```
const _loginInfo: any = await AuthFacade.login(credentials);
```

and the facade function

```
static async login(credentials: LoginCredentials): Promise<{ userId: number, token: string }> {
    const query = new Query({
        name: this.PROCS.LOGIN,
        arguments: credentials
    });
    return DB.query(query);
}
```

same coding is working on the local and it was working on heroku as well. But all of sudden I am getting this issue. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was problem with connection of pgsql. I was using the version 7 of `pg`, i guess that is not working with HeroKu. So I updated the version of pg

```
"pg": "^8.5.1",
```

and updated the pool config

```
const Pool = require("pg-pool");
import nodeEnvFile = require("node-env-file");
import { Query } from "src/models/query";
nodeEnvFile(".env");

const config = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_IP,
    database: process.env.DB,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    max: 5, // max number of connection can be open to database
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
};

const pool = new Pool(config);

export class DB {
    static async query(queryInfo: Query): Promise<any> {
        // to hold undefined values while stringfy json
        const replacer = (_key, value) => typeof value === "undefined" ? null : value;
        let _arguments = "()";
        if (queryInfo.arguments) {
            _arguments = `('${JSON.stringify(queryInfo.arguments, replacer)}'::json)`;
        }
        const query = `select * from ${queryInfo.name} ${_arguments} as info;`;
        console.log(query);
        try {
            return pool.query(query)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.rows[0].info;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Db Error : ", err);
                    throw err;
                });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("err", err);
            throw err;
        }
    }
}
```

now it is working